# Shouldn't it give some error coz we are trying to access the previous index using previous() when we have only one element in the LinkedList

Tags: java, iterator

I have included many SoP statements just to see what is happening in the code.

When this line

```
addInOrder(placesToVisit, "Sydney");
```

is executed, the `while` loop in the `addInOrder()` method will not be executed coz there is no element in the `LinkedList` and `hasNext()` will return false, "Sydney" will be inserted at index 0.

Now when

```
addInOrder(placesToVisit, "Melbourne");
```

is executed, the control will enter into the `while` loop in `addInOrder()` method. As "Melbourne" has to be inserted before the "Sydney" to get list in Lexographical order, `compareTo()` will return a value > 0. Now in this block we have used the `previous()` method to move the cursor before the "Sydney(index = 0)", but before index 0, its null or -1, also I have printed the `previousIndex()` value that is -1, still it is working.

Here is the output:

```
nextIndex: 0
previousIndex: -1
```

This printed before going into while loop

```
Now visiting Sydney
=============================
nextIndex: 0
previousIndex: -1
nextIndex: 0
nextIndex: 1
```

Here nextIndex = 1, that means, currentIndex = 0, the how can the previousIndex is also 0;

```
previousIndex: 0
counter 1
6
comparision > 0
nextIndex: 1
previousIndex() 0
```

Here nextIndex = 1, that means, currentIndex = 0, then how can be the previousIndex also 0 ? Is should be -1

```
Now visiting Melbourne
Now visiting Sydney
=============================
Now visiting Melbourne
Now visiting Sydney
=============================
```

Please explain why is it working. When we use previous() on index 0 and try to insert something, it should give some error or something. Isn't t?

```
public class Launch {

    static int counter;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<String> placesToVisit = new LinkedList<String>();
            
        addInOrder(placesToVisit, "Sydney");
        printList(placesToVisit);
        addInOrder(placesToVisit, "Melbourne");
        printList(placesToVisit);

        printList(placesToVisit);
    }



    private static void printList(LinkedList<String> linkedList)
    {
        Iterator<String> i = linkedList.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("Now visiting " + i.next());
        }
        System.out.println("=============================");
    }

    
    
    
    private static boolean addInOrder(LinkedList<String> linkedList, String newCity)
    {
        
        ListIterator<String> stringListIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
        System.out.println("nextIndex: " + stringListIterator.nextIndex());
        System.out.println("previousIndex: " + stringListIterator.previousIndex());
        
        while(stringListIterator.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println("nextIndex: " + stringListIterator.nextIndex());
            
            int comparison = stringListIterator.next().compareTo(newCity);
            
            System.out.println("nextIndex: " + stringListIterator.nextIndex());
            System.out.println("Here nextIndex = 1, that means, currentIndex = 0, then how can be the previousIndex also 0 ? Is should be -1");
            System.out.println("previousIndex: " + stringListIterator.previousIndex());
                        
            counter++;
            System.out.println("counter "+ +counter);
            System.out.println(comparison);
            if(comparison == 0)
            {
                // equal, do not add
                System.out.println(newCity + " is already in the list. So discarded.");
                System.out.println("comarision = 0");
                System.out.println();
                return false;
            }
            else if(comparison > 0)
            {
                //move control to previous position and add the new item
                System.out.println("comarision > 0");
                System.out.println("nextIndex: " + stringListIterator.nextIndex());
                System.out.println("previousIndex() "+stringListIterator.previousIndex());
                System.out.println("Here nextIndex = 1, that means, currentIndex = 0, then how can be the previousIndex also 0 ? Is should be -1");
                stringListIterator.previous();
                stringListIterator.add(newCity);
                System.out.println();
                return true; 
            }
            else if(comparison < 0)
            {
                // Do nothing, let it go ahead
                System.out.println("comarision < 0");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        stringListIterator.add(newCity);
        System.out.println("This printed before going into while loop");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Queue<T>` for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
When we use previous() on index 0 and try to insert something, it should give some error or something.
```

We know that in linked list concept , pointers are something which points to a node or element in a list.

But in Iterator there is concept of cursors, unlike pointers it is present between the Nodes/elements.

Here,

nextIndex() : gives cursor's next index value.

previousIndex(): gives cursor's precious index value.

In your case;

When nextIndex:0 and previousIndex:-1 , the cursor is just before index 0.
When nextIndex:1 and previousIndex:0, the cursor is between first and second element..

similarly for others..

Don't confuse between Cursors and Pointers.

Example:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Berlin");
list.add("Sydney");
list.add("London");
list.add("Italy");

// Get the list iterator
ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();


while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  int ii = iterator.previousIndex();
  int index = iterator.nextIndex();
  String element = iterator.next();
  System.out.println("PreviousIndex="+ii+", NextIndex=" + index + ", Element=" + element);
}
```

Output:

```
PreviousIndex=-1, NextIndex=0, Element=Berlin
PreviousIndex=0, NextIndex=1, Element=Sydney
PreviousIndex=1, NextIndex=2, Element=London
PreviousIndex=2, NextIndex=3, Element=Italy
```